# User object .save() does not save after upgrading django 2.1 => 2.2

Tags: django, django-models

I am experiencing a very strange bug where I can create and save a `User` from the django shell, but when I exit and reopen the shell, the `User` disappears.

This is in a prod-like environment with a proper backing DB. The issue goes away if I downgrade Django 2.2.8 -> 2.1.7

```
>>> u = User(id=123131323122, first_name='hi', last_name='sup', email='test@mysupertest.com')
>>> u.set_password('foobar')
>>> u.save()
>>> User.objects.count()
1059790
>>> u.refresh_from_db()
>>> u
<User: test@mysupertest.com>
>>> cursor.execute("select * From my_users_table_name where id=123131323122")
1
now exiting InteractiveConsole...
myuser$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov 23 2019, 07:02:27)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from mypackage.models import User
>>> User.objects.count()
1059789
>>> User.objects.get(email='test@mysupertest.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
mypackage.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor(
>>> cursor.execute("select * From my_users_table_name where id=123131323122")
0
```

My `User` inherits from django's `AbstractUser` and does not override `save` or any other methods.

Something is definitely wonky with the 2.2 change on transaction autocommits. If I wrap the save in a `with transaction.atomic()` block, then it commits properly. This is not a acceptable workaround because I'm not going to wrap every `User.save()` call in my codebase. I have the default `AUTOCOMMIT=True` in `DATABASES`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this.

- Set the `mysqld` param `autocommit=1` (or the db param group if you're on AWS)
- Set `DATABASES[...]['OPTIONS']['init_command'] = 'SET autocommit=1'`

The root cause of the issue is that at the db level, `autocommit=0` which is inconsistent with `AUTOCOMMIT=True` in `DATABASES`.

A [patch](https://github.com/django/django/pull/10448) to [optimize single queries](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21171) is in 2.2:

> Django no longer always starts a transaction when a single query is
>   being performed, such as Model.save(), QuerySet.update(), and
>   Model.delete(). This improves the performance of autocommit by
>   reducing the number of database round trips.

In my case, what happens is single queries like `.save()` and `.update()` are no longer put it into a transaction block and thus a `COMMIT` statement does not get sent.

Since `autocommit` is disabled on the database side, the `save()` does not persist in storage. At the shell level, we are still in the transaction so we see our objects fine, but after we close the shell, the transaction is discarded which is why a second shell doesn't see the changes.